# Windows Server Backup "the parameter is incorrect" on Hyper-V Core

Tags: windows, remote-access, hyper-v-server-2012, truecrypt, windows-server-backup

In my lab I run a Hyper-V Server 2012 Core to run multiple test-systems virtualy. To backup my system I want to use the "Windows Server Backup" role/feature. This role/feature works fine on other systems (include Windows 2012 Server Core) but not with my free Hyper-V Server 2012 Core Edition with TrueCrypt.

**Problem:**
Starting a Backup on the Hyper-V Core over the Wbadmin command works fine (testet with c:). But if I want to schedule the backup over "Remote Computer Management" over the GUI, I receive the following error: "The parameter is incorrect" and I can't find any future information in e.g. the EventViewer. The only thing, which I can use from the GUI-Menu is "Recover" <- this works. "Backup Schedule..." and "Backup Once..." rises the same error.

See Printscreen:

[image]

**System:**

- Hyper-V Server 2012 6.2 (9200)
- Roles: File and Storage Service, Hyper-V
- Features: .NET Framework 3.5, .NET Framework 4.0, Windows Power Shell, Windows Server Backup, WoW64 Support
- TrueCrypt: Systempartition and all other Harddisks are encrypted

Comment: To clarify: When you run the backup locally everything works, but when you try to get things working via remote management things start failing? Are you using the same account locally and remotely?

Comment: The account is the same, just one time with the cmd (works) and the other time with the gui (don't works)

Comment: Can you add an unencrypted partition and see if you can back that up through the GUI?